# Printing multiple order receipts without clicking print button on E-pos Thermal Pinter using PHP

Tags: php, thermal-printer

Can we print order receipt automatically (without clicking on print button) using E-pos printer (thermal printer) using PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Some  years ago , i needed  to create order  system  with  php  .
It was  working on lan  , and there was idea to print  orders  on save (without  ctrl +p) 
It was done this way :

- Orders  were  generated  as html  and saved in specyfic  directory on
  server   (linux server)
- Every 15 sec (in cron)  was  running  bash script

Bash script checked  contents on folder with orders , and for every file there 
script initate print (lp  command) and delete  file after that.

Printer was of course connected to server

Solution was little complicated , but it worked without any problems

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

But did you try it with Thermal Printer ?

Comment: IMHO Printer is a  printer , if you have it  connected  and you have  drivers installed  (for linux  in described solution)  , then you should be able to print  from command line and bash script .

Comment: Thanks once again for your quick reply!!
But we want this to be done with Thermal Printer.